# I am trying to update my kali linux rolling 32 bit but i get the following error

Tags: kali-linux

```
root@kali:~# apt-get upgrade
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Calculating upgrade... Done
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
```

Comment: Why have you tagged this with [tag:windows-7] ? -- Also, there's no error there.

Answer (score 2):

If you have correct repository in sources list then linux is already upgrade to latest version. And you can make sure by following below steps:

1. Type this command in terminal `leafpad /etc/apt/sources.list`
2. Check if below line exists and make sure it don't have # symbol in front of it.

   deb http://http.kali.org/kali kali-rolling main contrib non-free

Now run these commands:

- apt-get clean
- apt-get update
- apt-get upgrade
- apt-get dist-upgrade

**Single line Command:** apt-get clean && apt-get update && apt-get upgrade && apt-get dist-upgrade

If this returns the same output then you are at latest version.

Hope it helps! :)